# Робота с HashMap & HashSet

Tags: java, java-8

*Изучаю коллекции, стараюсь подвести итоги по HashMap & HashSet если я в чём то не прав, пишите*

Я знаю что HashMap это просто массив с объектов Entry, которые в свою очередь содержат два объекта - это ключ и значение. Затем с ключа берется хешкод и по нему определяется в котором индексе будет лежать данный объект Entry. Каждый индекс массива это связанный список, так как индексы двух Энтри объектов могут совпасть и тогда под одним индесок будут находиться несколько Entry объектов (в связанном списке)

**Вопрос 1**: Тоесть hashmap это просто массив (`пусть ArrayList`), который содержит связаные списки (`пусть ArrayList <LinkedList>`) а те в свою очередь состоят из объектов Entry (`пусть ArrayList <LinkedList <Entry >>`), так?

**Вопрос 2**: Я так понимаю HashSet работает так же, массив из связанных списков (Бакетов), по хешкоду определяется индекс, но эти связаны списки (элементы массива) уже не содержат объекты Entry а сам объект который мы поместили в HashSet, да?

*По приведенному примеру не судите строго просто питаюсь на простых примерах понять данную концепцию*

Comment: На каких примерах?

Comment: ArrayList <LinkedList>, ArrayList <LinkedList <Entry >> і т. д.

Comment: Не пиши код в комментариях.